# Bitcoin address form validation JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, validation, bitcoin

[I've seen a few Bitcoin Address form validation scripts for various languages](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation), but surprisingly can't really find anything for two common web languages, Javascript and PHP.

Here's one for Python, but is there one for PHP and/or JS?

```
from hashlib import sha256

digits58 = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def decode_base58(bc, length):
    n = 0
    for char in bc:
        n = n * 58 + digits58.index(char)
    return n.to_bytes(length, 'big')

def check_bc(bc):
    bcbytes = decode_base58(bc, 25)
    return bcbytes[-4:] == sha256(sha256(bcbytes[:-4]).digest()).digest()[:4]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bc = '1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW62i'
    assert check_bc(bc)
    assert not check_bc( bc.replace('N', 'P', 1) )
    assert check_bc('1111111111111111111114oLvT2')
    assert check_bc("17NdbrSGoUotzeGCcMMCqnFkEvLymoou9j")
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing the code for you.

Comment: how else can I ask it? I just gave the Python as an example. Just looking for any insight really...

Comment: You can try this yourself - and if you are having problems with a specific part, after thorough research, you can ask about that part. If you want something to be done, hire. If you want to do it yourself, try

Comment: Why are people so toxic? SO is a Q+A site. He's asking a question. Not all code questions require that he waste time reinventing the wheel before he's allowed to ask if anyone is aware of existing solutions.

Comment: So you answered your own question... I just have a quick suggestion. If you are using the blockchain.info or coinbase api, all you have to do to verify the address is to send the money. Then have a try catch, and if it fails then the address is wrong.

Comment: I'm already talking to a live bitcoind, so I just ask the bitcoin daemon to validate the address.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here's a JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/XsCQq/2/) http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/XsCQq/2/

[And here's the full code upon which the JSFiddle is based](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28441300/check.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28441300/BigInt.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28441300/sha256.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="text">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var address = "1Eym7pyJcaambv8FG4ZoU8A4xsiL9us2zz";
if (check(address)) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "valid";
} else {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "invalid";
}


function check(address) {
  var decoded = base58_decode(address);     
  if (decoded.length != 25) return false;

  var cksum = decoded.substr(decoded.length - 4); 
  var rest = decoded.substr(0, decoded.length - 4);  

  var good_cksum = hex2a(sha256_digest(hex2a(sha256_digest(rest)))).substr(0, 4);

  if (cksum != good_cksum) return false;
  return true;
}

function base58_decode(string) {
  var table = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  var table_rev = new Array();

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 58; i++) {
    table_rev[table[i]] = int2bigInt(i, 8, 0);
  } 

  var l = string.length;
  var long_value = int2bigInt(0, 1, 0);  

  var num_58 = int2bigInt(58, 8, 0);

  var c;
  for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    c = string[l - i - 1];
    long_value = add(long_value, mult(table_rev[c], pow(num_58, i)));
  }

  var hex = bigInt2str(long_value, 16);  

  var str = hex2a(hex);  

  var nPad;
  for (nPad = 0; string[nPad] == table[0]; nPad++);  

  var output = str;
  if (nPad > 0) output = repeat("\0", nPad) + str;

  return output;
}

function hex2a(hex) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}

function a2hex(str) {
    var aHex = "0123456789abcdef";
    var l = str.length;
    var nBuf;
    var strBuf;
    var strOut = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      nBuf = str.charCodeAt(i);
      strBuf = aHex[Math.floor(nBuf/16)];
      strBuf += aHex[nBuf % 16];
      strOut += strBuf;
    }
    return strOut;
}

function pow(big, exp) {
    if (exp == 0) return int2bigInt(1, 1, 0);
    var i;
    var newbig = big;
    for (i = 1; i < exp; i++) {
        newbig = mult(newbig, big);
    }

    return newbig;
}

function repeat(s, n){
    var a = [];
    while(a.length < n){
        a.push(s);
    }
    return a.join('');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[And here is a PHP example](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=197407.msg2059485#msg2059485) [(assuming your have PHP BC-Math):](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

```
<?php

function checkAddress($address)
{
    $origbase58 = $address;
    $dec = "0";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($address); $i++)
    {
        $dec = bcadd(bcmul($dec,"58",0),strpos("123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz",substr($address,$i,1)),0);
    }

    $address = "";

    while (bccomp($dec,0) == 1)
    {
        $dv = bcdiv($dec,"16",0);
        $rem = (integer)bcmod($dec,"16");
        $dec = $dv;
        $address = $address.substr("0123456789ABCDEF",$rem,1);
    }

    $address = strrev($address);

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($origbase58) && substr($origbase58,$i,1) == "1"; $i++)
    {
        $address = "00".$address;
    }

    if (strlen($address)%2 != 0)
    {
        $address = "0".$address;
    }

    if (strlen($address) != 50)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (hexdec(substr($address,0,2)) > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return substr(strtoupper(hash("sha256",hash("sha256",pack("H*",substr($address,0,strlen($address)-8)),true))),0,8) == substr($address,strlen($address)-8);
}

?>
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I combined it all in a single module.  Here it is, wrapped in an anonymous function and minified.  It exposes a single global function: "checkAddress" and clocks in at only 5.1k: http://www.julianhaight.com/btcvalid.js

Comment: @tim-peterson - Looks like there is a problem with the base58_decode you are using.  I replaced it with this one:https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58 and it works better.  Updated my minified library (removing some unused stuff to, now clocks in at 3.9k).

Comment: JS code doesn't work on multisig bitcoin addresses, like 3P37h58Az9sqUv8vDW4c1UGgwB5cPKs8DB which is valid but detected as invalid by JS code.

Comment: it returns invalid address even if the address is VALID

Comment: Doesn't work for multisig address 3LutQT57xPExqBrYPUTpX8q1EJYgBCVC4s

Comment: Finally got this working bitcoinjs lib https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bitcoinjs-lib/0.2.0-1/bitcoinjs-min.js

Comment: @tim peterson : Above code is not working with address like '3B9HFDhmBVVpCLmkP5A6vUjwMmU73zAxed'

Comment: The links are dead and in the code provided in the answer the OP has left out the int2bigInt function. This answer is a total mess as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better version of @Tim-Peterson 's answer.  It fixes the base58 implementation he was using (which would not validate the address "12EJmB3cMGRNveskzA7g7kxW32gSbo2dHF".

I combined the validation code with all the needed libraries and removed a lot that wasn't needed.  It only exposes a single api: "checkAddress".  I created a little home-page for it, where you can download the module source or the minified version: http://www.julianhaight.com/javascript.shtml

The corrected base58_decode (from https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58):

```
// from https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58
// Base58 encoding/decoding
// Originally written by Mike Hearn for BitcoinJ
// Copyright (c) 2011 Google Inc
// Ported to JavaScript by Stefan Thomas
// Merged Buffer refactorings from base58-native by Stephen Pair
// Copyright (c) 2013 BitPay Inc

var ALPHABET = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
var ALPHABET_MAP = {}
for(var i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length; i++) {
  ALPHABET_MAP[ALPHABET.charAt(i)] = i
}
var BASE = 58

function base58_decode(string) {
  if (string.length === 0) return []

  var i, j, bytes = [0]
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var c = string[i]
    if (!(c in ALPHABET_MAP)) throw new Error('Non-base58 character')

    for (j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) bytes[j] *= BASE
    bytes[0] += ALPHABET_MAP[c]

    var carry = 0
    for (j = 0; j < bytes.length; ++j) {
      bytes[j] += carry

      carry = bytes[j] >> 8
      bytes[j] &= 0xff
    }

    while (carry) {
      bytes.push(carry & 0xff)

      carry >>= 8
    }
  }

  // deal with leading zeros
  for (i = 0; string[i] === '1' && i < string.length - 1; i++) bytes.push(0)

  bytes = bytes.reverse()
  output = '';
  for (i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
      output += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Great stuff @Julian, can you perhaps explain why that Bitcoin address doesn't validate?

Comment: @timperterson I dug down as far as the base58-decode.  It was giving the wrong result from that function.  I didn't dig further into it since I had a working replacement for it.  I note the replacement function I used features a section labeled "deal with leading zeros" and I think the bad address did have leading zeros in it.  I posted the working code here, so you can compare how it's b58decode differs if you like: http://www.julianhaight.com/btcvalid.source.js

Comment: The above code is working for address like '3B9FDFDhmBVVpCLmkP5A6vUjwMmU83zAPed'..?

Comment: @Codebrekers, other apps also says that address is bad.  Were did you get it?  Is it supposed to be bad or good?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple PHP library to do this based on the answers above. It can be found [at my related github repo](https://github.com/tenfef/btc_address_validator):

```
<?php
class Btc_address_validator {

    /**
     * [validate description]
     * @param  String $address BTC Address string
     * @return Boolean validation result
     */
    public function validate($address)
    {        
        $addr = $this->decode_base58($address);
        if (strlen($addr) != 50)
        {
          return false;
        }        
        $check = substr($addr, 0, strlen($addr) - 8);
        $check = pack("H*", $check);
        $check = strtoupper(hash("sha256", hash("sha256", $check, true)));
        $check = substr($check, 0, 8);
        return $check == substr($addr, strlen($addr) - 8);
    }
    private function encode_hex($dec)
    {
        $hexchars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        $return = "";
        while (bccomp($dec, 0) == 1)
        {
            $dv = (string) bcdiv($dec, "16", 0);
            $rem = (integer) bcmod($dec, "16");
            $dec = $dv;
            $return = $return . $hexchars[$rem];
        }
        return strrev($return);
   }
    /**
    * Convert a Base58-encoded integer into the equivalent hex string representation
    *
    * @param string $base58
    * @return string
    * @access private
    */
    private function decode_base58($base58)
    {
        $origbase58 = $base58;    
        $base58chars = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
        $return = "0";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($base58); $i++)
        {
          $current = (string) strpos($base58chars, $base58[$i]);
          $return = (string) bcmul($return, "58", 0);
          $return = (string) bcadd($return, $current, 0);
        }
        $return = $this->encode_hex($return);
        //leading zeros
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($origbase58) && $origbase58[$i] == "1"; $i++)
        {
          $return = "00" . $return;
        }
        if (strlen($return) % 2 != 0)
        {
          $return = "0" . $return;
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Address (example: 3QJmV3qfvL9SuYo34YihAf3sRCW3qSinyC) is not valid in many the PHP examples. One of the example which works fine especially to the above address is:

[Click here to see the PHP Function to validate Bitcoin Address](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation#PHP)

Comment: Link is not working more, can you please provide latest link or code for the same

Answer (score 1):

For those using javascript, you can use [wallet-address-validator](https://github.com/ognus/wallet-address-validator) javascript plugin.

```
<script src="wallet-address-validator.min.js"></script>

// WAValidator is stored in the windows object
```

**networkType** - Optional. Use 'prod' (default) to enforce standard address, 'testnet' to enforce testnet address and 'both' to enforce nothing.

```
var valid = WAValidator.validate('12h7E1q5UUoPgZ1VtcYb57maFF9Cbk4u5X','BTC','both');
if(valid){
    alert('This is a valid address');
} else {
    alert('Address INVALID');
}
// will alert "This is a valid address"

var valid = WAValidator.validate('12h7E1q5UUoPgZ1VtcYb57maFF9Cbk4u5X', 'ETH', 'both');
if(valid){
    alert('This is a valid address');
} else {
    alert('Address INVALID');
}
// will alert "Address INVALID"
```

Comment: This will crash if the currency is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short and modern implementation in Javascript which depends on [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js):

```
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256'
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

function isBTCAddress (address) {
  if (!/^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$/.test(address)) return false
  const bufferLength = 25
  let buffer = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)
  const digits58 = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    const num = digits58.indexOf(address[i])
    // buffer = buffer * 58 + num
    let carry = 0
    for (var j = bufferLength - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
      // num < 256, so we just add it to last
      const result = buffer[j] * 58 + carry + (j === bufferLength - 1 ? num : 0)
      buffer[j] = result % (1 << 8)
      carry = Math.floor(result / (1 << 8))
    }
  }
  // check whether sha256(sha256(buffer[:-4]))[:4] === buffer[-4:]
  const hashedWords1 = sha256(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(buffer.slice(0, 21)))
  const hashedWords = sha256(hashedWords1).words
  // get buffer[-4:] with big-endian
  const lastWordAddress = new DataView(buffer.slice(-4).buffer).getInt32(0, false)
  const expectedLastWord = hashedWords[0]
  return lastWordAddress === expectedLastWord
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice REGEX from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24205650/4675176) that I have made into a function for you. Only works with non-segwit addresses.

```
function validate_bitcoin_address(btc_address)
 {
     return btc_address.match("^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$") !== null;
 }

 alert(validate_bitcoin_address("16CbQcqDtBak5NzPbmFP1v9Pi4DwP5G4Wn")); //example usage
```

The regex matches strings that:

- Starts with 1 or 3
- Afterwards, 25 to 34 characters of either a-z, A-Z, or 0-9 but not l, I, O and 0

The REGEX excludes characters that are not allow in bitcoin addresses (l, I, O and 0)

Comment: This answer works for some but cannot validate all wallets as BTC addresses can start with *bc* (Segwit)

Comment: @NicosKaralis Thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Hi, is this answer able to check for BTC addresses that start with bc?

Answer (score 0):

This works for each address format (today) https://github.com/Merkeleon/php-cryptocurrency-address-validation.

It needs [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), so probably... `sudo apt install php-bcmath`